# django-rosetta stop working due to google api changes, any alternative?

Tags: django, google-translate, django-rosetta

I have used django-rosetta in my project for translation, it stop working due to google api changes, giving following error

> Please use Translate v2. See
>   http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html

Is there any alternative ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django-rosetta 0.6.3 (just released) uses the Bing translation API. It's not as good, but seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to try [transifex.com](http://transifex.com) - they have really convinient git-like client for pushing/pulling translation to their cloud server. After that you can give translators an access to translate content in user-friendly web-interface. It is free until the reasonable quota.